# active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unable to use the latest version of composite_primary_keys (5.0.13) without it installing activesupport and activemodel 3.2.13. I do not want an upgrade to 3.2.13 as I am using rails 3.2.12 and prefer activesupport and activemodel 3.2.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that installing composite_primary_keys from the cmdline installs activesupport 3.2.13 and activemodel 3.2.13 along with it even though there are no mentioned dependencies here rubygems.org/gems/composite_primary_keys. I avoided installing activesupport and activemodel 3.2.13 versions by using:

gem install composite_primary_keys --ignore-dependencies